# Windows 10 mobile emulator

Tags: uwp

I am trying install windows 10 mobile emulator on my lap top the version is 14393. And i have downloaded the installer of size 1.1 mb from official site. it downloaded another file of size about 2.2 gb and it finished but it is not installed properly. it shows up in control panel but not visual studio and hyper-v manager. Uninstall and change options in control panel doesn't do anything but repair will open and after few time it will end up with a fatal error. now what should i do? unable to uninstall or change

Screenshot of error while repairing

[image]

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

Comment: that is the where i have downloaded. After several attempts(i actually didn't know which one worked). i have it running but cant uninstall or change.

Comment: And what is your VS version? Did you get a `EmulatorSetup.exe` after you downloaded? What else you got? In programs and features did you see `Microsfot Emulator- Windows 10.0.14393.0`?

Comment: Ya i run 'EmulatorSetup.exe'. and i can find 'Microsoft Emulator- Windows 10.0.14393.0 ' in programs and features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your situation that the setup was corrupted after installation and, therefore, fails with above error during un-installation, you may need to fix it firstly and un-install. For how to do this please download [Program Install and Uninstall troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed) and fix.Then empty all temporary folders and try re-install again.

If still have issues, please try the resolutions on [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/834484/you-receive-an-error-1603-a-fatal-error-occurred-during-installation-error-message-when-you-try-to-install-a-windows-installer-package). You may need to install the package to another drive and grant Full Control permissions to the SYSTEM account as the document mentioned.

If you still have issues after then, please try to provide the installer logs. For how to enable windows install logging please reference [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/223300/how-to-enable-windows-installer-logging).

Comment: I will try that.